# Amazon Redshift authentication issue

Tags: excel, vba

This is my code to connect to Redshift using a form that has username and password fields.

```
If TextBox_username.Value = "" Or TextBox_password.Value = "" Then
       MsgBox "Enter Username and Password"
    Else
         oConn.Open "Driver={Amazon Redshift (x86)};" & _
            "Server=" & strServerAddress & ";" & _
            "Port=123;" & _
            "Database=abc;" & _
            "Uid=" & strUsername & ";" & _
            "Pwd=" & strPassword & ";"
        oConn.commandTimeout = 600

        If oConn.State = 1 Then
        End If
    End If
```

The problem is if a user enters wrong credentials by mistake I get a runtime error as below:
[image]

How can I handle this error with a message saying that "Invalid Credentials" rather than giving a runtime error and asking to end? Thank you for your help

Comment: You handle errors with *error handling*. See `On Error` statement

Comment: [Here](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-error-handling/) is a pretty good tutorial for Errorhandling

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need to go to

```
Tools -> Options -> General -> Error trapping
```

and select

```
Break on Unhandled errors
```

add to your code:

```
Public Sub Teste()
On Error GoTo Err
    If TextBox_username.Value = "" Or TextBox_password.Value = "" Then
       MsgBox "Enter Username and Password"
    Else
       oConn.Open "Driver={Amazon Redshift (x86)};" & _
                "Server=" & strServerAddress & ";" & _
                "Port=123;" & _
                "Database=abc;" & _
                "Uid=" & strUsername & ";" & _
                "Pwd=" & strPassword & ";"
       oConn.commandTimeout = 600

       If oConn.State = 1 Then
       End If
    End If
Exit Sub
    Err:
    Msgbox Err.Description 'Your custom message
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer Jorge. I have a follow up question. If I share this excel sheet with someone else, do they have to do the same steps of Tools -> Options -> General -> Error trapping or no? It's just for the guy who writes the code?

Comment: As far as i know you cant change this is runtime, except in access.

Comment: But you can check the registry key in `Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VBA\7.1\Common\BreakOnServerErrors` and change it to the value you want!

Comment: 7.1 is the version i m using

Comment: got it. Thank you for the answer.